# filtering time range in datetime field in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got a weird problem when I was doing the time range filtering in sqlalchemy.
There is a datetime column in Event table called startDate. I was writing the query to return all the events that have the starting time between 6pm and 11:59pm (doesn't matter which date).

I have the following code,

```
from sqlalchemy import and_, Date, Time, cast
import datetime
startingTime = datetime.time(18, 0, 0)
endingTime = datetime.time(23, 59, 59)
```

If I run,

```
results = session.query(Event).filter(and_(cast(Event.startDate, Time)>=startingTime, cast(Event.startDate, Time)<=endingTime).all()
```

I got no result (for sure there are events in this range).

But if I run,

```
results = session.query(Event).filter(cast(Event.startDate, Time)>=endingTime).all()
```

It returns all rows in the table.

If I filter by dates,

```
results = session.query(Event).filter(and_(cast(Event.startDate, Date)>=one_date, cast(Event.startDate, Date)<=another_date).all()
```

results are correct!

Let's say the startDate of Event_A is 2013-11-27T19:30:00, and

```
result = session.query(cast(Event.startDate, Time)).filter(Event.eventName=='Event_A').one()[0]
result >= startingTime ----> returns True
result <= endingTime ----> returns True
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure that if you're including code that you use the builtin formatting features of StackOverflow. You can highlight your code and click the on `{}` button in the text editor toolbar to do this.

Comment: @CharlsGao: it would be very useful if for each `SA query` that you showed you would also add the resulting `SQL` statement. You can see this by enabling logging via passing setting `engine.echo=True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I guess it is because I am using sql server 2005, and DATE and TIME object will only be supported by the version after sql server 2008.

I found an alternative way to accomplish this task by using func.convert:

```
session.query(TableName).filter(func.convert(func.VARCHAR(8), TableName.datetimefield, 8) >= datetime.time(0,0)).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

i cannot replicate this behavior.

to debug, do this in steps:

```
session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) > '00:00:00').all() 
# > all
session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) > '23:59:59').all()
# > []
session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) < '23:59:59').all()
# > all
session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) > datetime.time(0,0)).all()
# > all
session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) > datetime.time(23,59,59)).all()
# > []
session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) < datetime.time(23,59,59)).all()
# > all
session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) < datetime.time(23,59,59)).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) > datetime.time(0,0)).all()
# > all
session.query(TableName).filter(and_(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) < datetime.time(23,59,59), cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) > datetime.time(0,0)).all()
# > all
```

Comment: I ran 

session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) > datetime.time(0,0)).all()
returns all 
but 
session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) < datetime.time(23,59,59)).all()
returns []

Comment: did `session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) < '23:59:59').all()` return everything?

Comment: well, session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) < '23:59:59').all() returns empty result ([]), but session.query(TableName).filter(cast(TableName.some_datetimefield, Time) > '00:00:00').all() is actually returning everything.